# Getting a lot of identical disk errors: blk_update_request: critical medium error

Tags: disk, smart

On my home server I'm getting a lot of identical errors:

```
blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev nvme0n1, sector 1416772496 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
```

As far as I understand this means the disk is broken at that specific sector? it is always the same sector. it's also less than 1 year old (but heavily used at least for home use)

I ran

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/nvme0n1
```

And got below output:

> === START OF SMART DATA SECTION === SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
>
> SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02) Critical Warning:
> 0x00 Temperature:                        54 Celsius Available Spare:
> 100% Available Spare Threshold:          5% Percentage Used:
> 4% Data Units Read:                    147,254,130 [75.3 TB] Data
> Units Written:                 107,209,297 [54.8 TB] Host Read
> Commands:                 7,513,502,042 Host Write Commands:
> 562,886,094 Controller Busy Time:               31,164 Power Cycles:
> 79 Power On Hours:                     7,476 Unsafe Shutdowns:
> 11 Media and Data Integrity Errors:    10,398,903 Error Information
> Log Entries:      10,398,983 Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
> Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0

Here the drive passes the test but I'm not sure what the constant error mean? Is there any way to know what files are/were in that sector?

What happens if I reformat the drive, will it automatically get rid of that sector?

Eg I want to know what data I lost and how to get rid of the error messages.

EDIT: this is an ssd just in case that wasn't clear yet.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal behavior for an SSD that sectors die over time. SSDs have a chip designated to handle this and the redistribution of data across sectors. The "percentage used: 4%" means that 4% of your drive is dead. SSD's have a limited lifespan. As long as you keep some space unused there is no harm. If your drive is nearly full (exluding dead sectors), it might result in problems because sectors are reused more often and it's also harder to redistribute data when a sector dies.